# How to upload an attachments in Go using these package "google.golang.org/appengine/mail"

Tags: database, google-app-engine, go

Below is my code that I am trying to send with an attachment.

```
    msg := &mail.Message{
                    Sender: "kasireddy002@gmail.com",
                    To:     []string{addr},
          Attachments : []Attachment{
                           Name :"file name",
                            Data :[]byte,
                        ContentID :"fileid",
                      },

                    Subject: "Welcome to Simplyst Health: Verify your account",
    if err := mail.Send(context, msg); err != nil {
                    log.Errorf(ctx, "Alas, my user, the email failed to sendeth: err)
                }
```

When I am trying to save my code it is throwing an error.

ERROR:

```
cannot use []Attachment literal (type []Attachment) as type []"google.golang.org/appengine/mail".Attachment in field value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change it to

```
msg := &mail.Message{
    Sender: "kasireddy002@gmail.com",
    To:     []string{addr},
    Attachments: []mail.Attachment{
        {
            Name:      "file name",
            Data:      []byte{},
            ContentID: "fileid",
        },
    },
    Subject: "Welcome to Simplyst Health: Verify your account",
}
```

Just to point out the issues with your code:

- There was an error check within the definition of your `mail.Message`
- The `Attachment` type was missing the package name, `mail`
- As you were creating a slice of Attachments and not just one attachment, you needed to add extra `{}` around the attachment you wanted to add

Comment: `There was an error check within the definition of your mail.Message` - actually, this is a compilation error

Comment: @Ullaakut  Hi,I was able able to upload the document  but unable to read the content in it. i should give any value in Data .can you suggest me any changes if needed.

Comment: Since the data contains an empty slice of bytes, there won't be any content in your document. Simply add some next in the Data field for the attachment, like such: `Data: []byte("some data")` and you should end up with a file that has this string in it.

Comment: when i am giving string value it shows me an error :cannot use "some data" (type string) as type byte in array or slice literal . can you illustrate me.

Comment: You might have made a typo? See a working example of setting a slice of bytes using a string: https://play.golang.org/p/oZv48Motjw7